# sql Trigger ensuring 30 days between appointments not working

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Trying to create a trigger ensuring that there is at least 30 days between appointments but this doesn't seem to work:

```
delimiter //
create trigger time_between_doses
before insert on appointment
for each row
begin 
if datediff((select appointment_time from appointment where new.patientSSN = patientSSN), 
new.appointment_time) < 30
    THEN SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
    SET MYSQL_ERRNO = 9996,
    MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Not 30 days between appointments for this patient';
end if;
end //
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you want to check would use `exists`.  It is not 100% clear what the "30 days" means.  Presumably you want to know if this returns any rows:

```
select a.*
from appointment a
where new.patientSSN = a.patientSSN and
      new.appointment_time < a.appointment_time + interval 30 day;
```

One thing that is unclear is whether the 30 day limit goes into the past as well as the future.  And whether it applies to only to appointments in the past or also to appointments in the future.

Your version is an error waiting to happen because you are using a subquery where a single value is expected.  If the subquery returns multiple rows, then the code will generate an error.  The above logic should be used with `exists`.